# Handlebars.js in Node.js, missing parser

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to include [Handlebars.js](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/) in node.

In the base.js file it requires a file called parser:

```
var handlebars = require("./parser").parser;
```

This file doesn't seem to be included in the package. Is this supposed to be generated somehow?

**Update:**
I think I get it. I need to compile it using the included ruby files. Never used ruby, let me see if I can get this Rakefile to work. -Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need `handlebars` additional features, I would just use `mustache`.   `Mustache` templates are 100% compatible with `handlebars` if you choose to update latter.

```
npm install mustache
```

and to include it into a file

```
var mustache = require('mustache');
```

Comment: Thanks Lime. I did end up getting handlebars to work. Using Mustache I think would have been an easier solution though.

To get handlebars to work I simply installed ruby, rake, and a few gems. Then raked the file to compile parser.js. Then just updated some of the file paths in the require("") lines.

Comment: @Nick Some how I managed to just get a bounty for this question?  oh well thats cool.

Comment: I saw that. do you think I should post a detailed response of what I did? It looks like handlebars has been updated since then.